# Generating all the substring of a given length using yield

Tags: c#, string, yield-return

I need to generate all the substring of a given length, of a string.

For example all the substrings of length 3 of "abcdefg" are:

```
abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
```

For this task I wrote this function:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> AllSubstringsLength(string input, int length)
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length - length; i++)
    {
        result.Add(input.Substring(i, length));
    }
    return result;
}
```

that I use like this:

```
foreach(string s in AllSubstringsLength("abcdefg",3))
    System.Console.WriteLine(s);
```

I wonder if it is possible to write the same function avoiding the variable `result` and using `yield`

Comment: Should be linQ-able with a `enumerable.Range`, `where select`  etc. if the aim is just to be able to use it in a for each with lazy evaluation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, this is possible

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> AllSubstringsLength(string input, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i + length > input.Length) yield break;
            yield return input.Substring(i, length);
        }
    }
```

You can also avoid `if` in the loop by modifying a bit the condition to
`i <= input.Length - length`, thus your method becomes:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> AllSubstringsLength(string input, int length)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= input.Length - length; i++)
        {
            yield return input.Substring(i, length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can remove the `if` statement if you update `i < input.Length - length`

Comment: i <= input.Length - length

Comment: indeed, how embarrassing :(